# Loop googleanalyticsR - Error in if (nrow(out) < all_rows { : argument is of length zero

Tags: r, google-api, google-analytics-api

I am using the googleanalyticsR to download all the data I can from Google Analytics. My objective it is to build a small dataframe to analyze.

To download all the data I created a loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(metricsarray)) {
  print(paste(i))
  tryCatch(   google_analytics_4(my_id, 
                                 date_range = c(start_date, end_date ),
                                 metrics =  metricsarray[i],
                                 dimensions = c( 'transactionId'),
                                 max = -1)) %>%
    assign(gsub(" ", "", paste( "metricsarray",i, sep="")), ., inherits = TRUE)
}
```

The loop runs from 1 to 11 with no problems, i.e. Prints the number of i and gives me the message:

> Downloaded [3537] rows from a total of [3537]

But I got this error when it reaches i = 12 in metricsarray[i]:

> 2017-10-04 10:37:56> Downloaded [0] rows from a total of [].
>       Error in if (nrow(out) < all_rows) { : argument is of length zero

I used the tryCatch, but with no effect, it continues. My objetive was that it would continue to test each of the metricsarray[i] until the end.
Also, also continue when it finds the error:

> JSON fetch error: Selected dimensions and metrics cannot be queried
>        together.

I am new to using the googleanalytics API in R, feel free to suggest solutions, articles or anything we might think it will help me gain more knowledge about this.
Thank you,

Comment: The tryCatch should work for your use case, what happens instead? I do similar and it works ok. Feel free to raise an issue on the GitHub if it's easier.

Answer (score 0):

> JSON fetch error: Selected dimensions and metrics cannot be queried
>    together.

Not all Google analytics dimensions and metrics can be queried together.  The main reasons for that is either the data doesnt exist or the data would make no sence.

The best way to test what metadata can be queried together is to check the [dimensions and metrics reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets).   Invalid items will be grayed out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I know that, but I  would like to download all possible data combinations, and for the loop to ignore that error when that is the response from the server. 
But more important than that, is for the loop to ignore when it finds no data (`Error in if (nrow(out) < all_rows) { : argument is of length zero`) and just pass on to try to download another metric from the google analytics server.